# How do I fix a non-starting "Microsoft Key Distribution Service"? (not to be confused with Kerberos KDS)

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain-controller, bitlocker, managed-service-accounts

The `Microsoft Key Distribution Service` is not starting on my DC (kdssvc.dll) and when I look at the event log under Microsoft\Kdssvc, I see the events:

> Event ID 4001 
>   Group Key Distribution Service failed to start. Status
>   0x80070020.
>
> Event ID 4007
>   Group Key Distribution Service cannot connect to the
>   domain controller on local host.  Status 0x80070020.  Group Key
>   Distribution Service cannot be started because of the error.  Please
>   contact administrators to resolve the issue.

The error 0x80070020 indicates a file lock of some type.

Does anyone know how I can fix this error? Troubleshooting on the net for this is a bit sparse and is confused with the KDC.

For clarification: This question is not about Kerberos, instead it's about the service account that handles Group Managed Service Accounts (gMSA), Bitlocker, and Windows Activation Services in a corporate environment.

**Update** here is the procmon

[image]

Comment: 0x80070020 = ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION (the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.) run procmon while trying to start the service and look for ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION results. Here you could see which file causes it.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I did it, not sure if I did it right - see above...

Comment: this is not the error. look for ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION entries

Comment: is your DC in a top-level OU? Or is it in a subOU?

Comment: @SamErde unfortunately, they *can* be moved out of it.  
This doesn't means they *should*, though.

Answer (score 0):

Validate that your DC is in the Default "Domain Controller" OU or the Service will fail.  This is the only apparent impact of moving a DC that we experienced.